# Addon not working

Tags: add-on

I got a new add-on and i installed it, i tried to put the add-on (unzipped) in the add-on folder and when i try to use the add-on in the 3d-view i get this message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/var/folders/1z/c63tvc6x6p53dg3mjsbwdrxr0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/F1104D03-005A-40B9-A00A-460ACE763FE0/d/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.80/scripts/addons/fluent/__init__.py", line 4427, in invoke
    bpy.ops.wm.polydraw('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
  File "/private/var/folders/1z/c63tvc6x6p53dg3mjsbwdrxr0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/F1104D03-005A-40B9-A00A-460ACE763FE0/d/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.80/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 198, in __call__
    ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), C_dict, kw, C_exec, C_undo)
RuntimeError: Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/var/folders/1z/c63tvc6x6p53dg3mjsbwdrxr0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/F1104D03-005A-40B9-A00A-460ACE763FE0/d/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.80/scripts/addons/fluent/__init__.py", line 4136, in invoke
    self.bool_target, self.had_latest_bevel, had_weighted_normals = duplicate_obj(self.original_bool_target)
  File "/private/var/folders/1z/c63tvc6x6p53dg3mjsbwdrxr0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/F1104D03-005A-40B9-A00A-460ACE763FE0/d/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.80/scripts/addons/fluent/__init__.py", line 1210, in duplicate_obj
    depth = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'evaluated_depsgraph_get'

location: /private/var/folders/1z/c63tvc6x6p53dg3mjsbwdrxr0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/F1104D03-005A-40B9-A00A-460ACE763FE0/d/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.80/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py:198



location: <unknown location>:-1
```

Anyone know what's the problem?

Comment: Usually you don't unzip and put the addon anywhere, you just click "install" in the Preferences > Addon panel, unless you have a reason to do it this way?

Comment: I tried both ways, but it gives me the same result, that's why i tried this way

Comment: Suggest getting a more recent version of 2.8.  `context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()` was added _circa_ last month.  _It not being defined for version OP is using is error issue above_ Often for addons it is more appropriate to post an issue to where you obtained it, especially if you paid for it. Feel it is beyond  the purpose of this site to fix commercial addons. @moonboots do not think it is an installation issue, the `__init__.py` and folder location look correct in error message above.  If you know what you are doing it is perfectly fine to unzip addon's folder into blender addon folder